# How to assign a Category to a Page, when both are created on theme initiation?

Tags: themes

I'm finishing up work on my theme. Even though it's for personal use I want to automate the creation of some essential pages, so that it will already be functional on activation.

I've added the following code to my `functions.php`, and both the Category and the Page are successfully created. However, there is no automatic assigning of the Category to the newly created Page. I'm relying on the *Add Categories To Pages plugin* for this functionality, and I suspect that's why it isn't working properly

```
// let's create some stuff on init
    if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin())       //check for init
    {    

        // create categories 
        if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) 
            {
                require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');    
                if (!get_cat_ID('plants')) {wp_create_category('plants');}
            }

        // create pages
        if (get_page_by_title('potato') == NULL)       //check if page exists
        {
           $new_page_title = 'potato';

             $post_cat = get_term_by('name', 'plants', 'category');
             $post_cat = $post_cat->term_id;

           $new_page_content = 'coming soon';
               //$new_page_template = 'template-page-with-subnav.php';
           $post_parent = '';
           $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);

           $new_page = array(
                   'post_type'     => 'page',
                 'post_category'   => $post_cat,
                   'post_title'    => $new_page_title,
                   'post_content'  => $new_page_content,
                   'post_status'   => 'publish',
                   'post_author'   => 1,
                   'post_parent'   => $post_parent, );
           if(!isset($page_check->ID))
              {
                $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
                if(!empty($new_page_template))
                {update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', $new_page_template);}
              }

        }

    }
```

After activating the theme, I have the expected Category and Page created, but no link between them.

Comment: I think `post_category` is expected to be an array of term ids.

Comment: @Milo i tried modifying to `post_category' => array($post_cat),` and it made no difference :( **$post_cat** returns a single numeric value, so it should work either way.

Comment: `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` is perhaps what you need.

Comment: @Milo - Thanks for your continuing help. i added `register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );`  to my functions.php, after creating the category, and prior to creating the page. but the association is still not being created. from the codex it looks like register_taxonomy_for_object_type is used to allow the use of the taxonomy - not to specifically assign a taxonomy to a specific object, correct?

Comment: yes, if you look at the source for `wp_insert_post`, you will see where it checks first that `post_category` is an array, and second that the taxonomy is registered for use with the post type you are trying to associate it to.

Answer (score 0):

figured out how to accomplish my task :

```
// function to fetch tag ID from name
   function get_tag_ID($tag_name) 
   { $tag = get_term_by('name', $tag_name, 'post_tag'); if ($tag) { return $tag->term_id; } else { return NULL;}    }

// add categories & tag taxonomy to pages
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'page' ); 

// let's create some stuff on init
    if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin())       //check for init
    {  
        // create categories & tags
        if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'))
            {
                require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
                // categories
                $check = get_cat_ID('plants'); if(empty($check)) {wp_create_category('plants');}
                $check = get_cat_ID('animals'); if(empty($check)) {wp_create_category('animals');}

                //tags
                $check = get_tag_ID('tall'); if (empty($check)) {wp_create_tag('tall');}
                $check = get_tag_ID('short'); if (empty($check)) {wp_create_tag('short');}
            }

        // create pages
        $new_page_title = 'carrot';          // define PAGE TITLE
        $new_page_cat   = 'plants';          // define PAGE CATEGORY
        $new_page_tag   = array('tall');     // define PAGE TAGS

        $page_check = get_page_by_title($new_page_title);
        if(!isset($page_check->ID))           // verify new page is unique
            {
            $new_page = array(
            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'post_title'    => $new_page_title,
            'post_content'  => 'more coming soon',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_parent'   => '', );

            $post_cat = get_term_by('name', $new_page_cat, 'category');
            $post_cat = $post_cat->term_id;
            $new_page_cat = array($post_cat);

            $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);                   // create page
            wp_set_post_categories( $new_page_id,$new_page_cat, true ); // set category
            wp_set_post_tags( $new_page_id,$new_page_tag, true );       // set tags 
            }

    }
```

@Milo, thanks for your help :)

for anyone looking to do the same thing on the activation of their theme, this code works pretty well in all the testing i did : verifies that categories and tags to be created don't already exist, verifies that the page to be created doesn't already exist. page creation works and correctly links both category and tag to the created page. all the correct relationships show up when you look at your categories or tags index, so any searching by either should work correctly.

after theme activation you can use the *get_tag_ID()* function elsewhere in WP.

Pages will now be registered for both *Category* and *Tag* taxonomies, although coding or a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-category-to-pages/) will be required to provide Admin metaboxes.

cheers.